# user control with custom type dependency property (Bound)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I currently write an image viewer control that encapsulates a WPF Image Control and further stuff (Controls for applying filters and changing views). Here's the relevant portion of control's source code:

```
public partial class ImageViewPort : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BitmapSource _source;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageDescriptorSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageDescriptorSource",
                                 typeof(ImageDescriptor),
                                 typeof(ImageViewPort),
                                 new UIPropertyMetadata(ImageDescriptorSourceChanged));

    public ImageDescriptor ImageDescriptorSource
    {
        get { return (ImageDescriptor)GetValue(ImageDescriptorSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageDescriptorSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public BitmapSource Source //the image control binds to this beauty!
    {
        get { return _source; }
        set { _source = value; OnPropertyChanged("Source"); }
    }

   public ImageViewPort() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private static void ImageDescriptorSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageViewPort viewPort = (ImageViewPort)d;
        if (viewPort != null)
        {
            viewPort.TransformImage();
        }
    }

    private BitmapSource TransformImage()
    {
        //do something that sets the "Source" property to a BitmapSource
    }
}
```

The XAML Code (only relevant parts) of the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Name="viewPort">
<Image Source="{Binding ElementName=viewPort,Path=Source}"/>
</UserControl>
```

And finally the usage:

```
<WPF:ImageViewPort ImageDescriptorSource="{Binding Path=CurrentImage}"/>
```

In my window, I basically iterate a Collection and, as I do so, throw PropertyChanged notification for the CurrentImage property. That works, the getter is called each time, so the binding seems to work.

What I would expect to happen now is that the PropertyChanged-Callback of my UserControl is fired, but no such thing happens (It never steps in there, I've tried using breakpoints). I've tried the same thing binding a primitive type (int), and that worked.

Do you see any flaw in my implementation? Why isn't the user control updating?
Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Cheers

Sebi

Comment: Check the output ... do you get any binding warnings? Also are you setting a new value? WPF knows when you try to set a value that is already set and ignores it. I would suggest thange the Metadata type to FrameworkPropertyMetadata and supply a proper default value.

Comment: this `{Binding ElementName=viewPort,Path=Source}` 
would imply that your `viewPort` element has `Source` DP, which doesn't seem to be the case, is that the XAMl you're actually using?

Comment: @dowhilefor : how stupid to forget about the data binding exceptions in my console window :) thanks for that!

Comment: @Dmitry : I think a CLR property is sufficient, otherwise all viewmodels would have to implement their members as DPs...

Comment: @Sebastian Edelmeier true enough. it'll work with most sceanrios. Your CLR setter should never get called, it exsits purely as a a virtual facade on top of your DP. In order for your PropertyChanged event to get fired you've to set your DP - which never happens. Check your your Source CLR property - it triggers no action affecting your DP whatsoever. You've to call this.SetValue(DP, value) for this to happen.

Comment: @Dmitry : You are right about the virtual facade thing. But in my case, the DP is of a custom type while the image control needs a BitmapSource bound to it. So, you could say, i use the PropertyChangedCallback to convert it and store it in an intermediate property...

Comment: @dowhilefor : the output of course did the trick! I found out I had declared the type ImageDescriptor twice! That was the consequence of a  refactoring, it seems...If you post this as an answer, You'll get the score!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output ... do you get any binding warnings? Also are you setting a new value? WPF knows when you try to set a value that is already set and ignores it. I would suggest thange the Metadata type to FrameworkPropertyMetadata and supply a proper default value.

To give this "comment" more value: Adding "PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High" on the binding gives alot more information about how the binding tries to get its value, which also helps alot, finding problems that are not errors for WPF.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, and even more so for adding information about the TraceLevel - that's what I've been looking for for a while now!